# Retagging old meta questions with [back-up]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, back-up

The "backup," "back-up," or "back it up" policy has become a staple of our site. In addition, we've seen a **lot** of questions concerning it on our meta.

That being said, there's no easy way to see discussion about this policy, as we have no tag for it and the [policy](/questions/tagged/policy) tag isn't on all of them.

I suggest that we go through old meta questions and add the new [back-up](/questions/tagged/back-up) tag to questions concerning the policy to make these questions easier to find.